# How to add a sub item/level to the child key of plist (multiple-levels)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist, user-input

i am trying to create a planner application on iphone. I would like to create a sub key/row in my plist in another view (That means, i'll first create the structure of the plist in one view, and in the other view i would like to add another item into the already created plist). I would want my plist to look like this:

> Root (Array)
>
> ```
>   Item 0 (Dictionary)
>         ProjectName (String)
>         Stages (Dictionary)
>                Analysis (Array)
>                        ^Item 0 (Dictionary) 
>                               Levels (String)
>                               Tools (String)
>                        ^Item 1 (Dictionary)
>                               Levels (String)
>                               Tools (String)
>                Develop (Array)
>
>  Item 1 (Dictionary)
>         ProjectName (String)
>         Stages (Dictionary)
>                Analysis (Array)
>                        ^Item 0 (Dictionary)
>                               Levels (String)
>                               Tools (String)
>                        ^Item 1 (Dictionary)
>                               Levels (String)
>                               Tools (String)
>                Develop (Array)
> ```

^ for now, i don't have the item 0 and item 1 in my Analysis array and i would like to add it in but i don't know the right codes to do it.

So in my first view, i would be able to add a new project and after adding, it will save in my plist as a dictionary, the first item 0 (i've code it that when the user saves the new project the stages dictionary with the analysis and develop array will be created in my plist as well).
-- there would be item 1, item 2 and so on if the user choose to add more projects.

After the user has created(saved) a new project, he/she can go to the second view where he/she could choose a stage (Analysis/Develop).

So example, the user chooses the Analysis stage, he/she would be taken to another view which allows the user to add level(s) for the certain stage.

The problem i am facing is how am i suppose to add another dictionary item with strings into my existing Analysis stage in the plist (how to add a new value/item into an existing dictionary/array(row) in the plist)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would do something like this:

```
[analysisArray addObject:newDictionary];
```

Is that what you mean?

EDIT: To replace the dictionary at item 0 with a new one:

```
int row = 0;
[analysisArray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:newDictionary]
```

To set an individual key at item 0:

```
int row = 0;
rowDictionary = [analysisArray objectAtIndex:row];
[rowDictionary setValue:value forKey:key];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply:) but if there is 2 items in the root array then how am i gonna specify which one i am going to add it into? (for example, i want to add another dictionary in item 0, how am i gonna code it so that it will save into item 0 not item 1 or creating a new item) thanks(:

Comment: thanks this works(: but what if i don't know which row i am adding to. For example if the user click item 0 in the first view table then im suppose to save it in item 0 but if he/she clicks item 1 i must save the data into item 1. Sorry for asking so many questions. Thank you for your time(:

Comment: Well, this is down to how you are building your user interface and responding to user events.  The row the user clicks on would be the row index of the array if there was a one to one mapping between your array and say a UITableView for instance.  In your didSelectCellAtIndexPath: has an index path that gives you the row.

Comment: Hi, sorry to trouble you once again. The codes works but every time i want to add a new item into the analysis array, it gets overwritten. 
NSArray *stage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:set, nil];
int row = 0;
newNote = [appDelegate.Courses objectAtIndex: row];
[newNote setValue:stage forKey:@"Analysis"];
[appDelegate.Courses writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
[newNote release];

Do you know what is wrong? Thank you. sorry for asking so many questions